# Excel Shapes.Range(Array("someName")) - whats the defined range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code snippet in Excel VBA:

```
With Worksheets("MLS").Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 1")).Fill
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(166, 166, 166)
    .Transparency = 0.3
End With
```

I don't know where "Rounded Rectangle 1" is defined and what kind of shape or range it refers to. It is not defined within the VBA Code, I have already tried searching the whole project for the name.

Where can I find the definition of "Rounded Rectangle 1" and what might have been the programmers intent in referring to a range/shape using this shapes/range/array construct?

Comment: It's the name of a shape on the MLS sheet. I'd guess it's a rounded rectangle ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Worksheets("MLS").Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 1"))` refers to a shape named "Rounded Rectangle 1" on the worksheet "MLS" so you won't find the definition you're looking for in your code, it's an object that exists on the worksheet.

`Worksheets("SheetName").Shapes.Range([arg])` is used to reference a subset of the shapes present on the named worksheet (i.e. objects in that sheet's `Shapes` collection). The argument of the `Shapes.Range` method can either be:

- An Integer, referring to the index of the shape in the `Shapes` collection
- A String, referring to the name of a shape in the `Shapes` collection.
- An Array containing strings and/or integers, referring to the names/indices of shapes in the `Shapes` collection.

In your specific case the use of `Array("Rounded Rectangle 1")` is unnecessary and the line in question could have been written as

```
Worksheets("MLS").Shapes.Range("Rounded Rectangle 1")
```

with the same effect, or even just

```
Worksheets("MLS").Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 1")
```

However if there were multiple Rounded Rectangles on your sheet then you would need to use the full fat reference your mystery programmer used, something along the lines of

```
Worksheets("MLS").Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 1", "Rounded Rectangle 2", "Rounded Rectangle 3"))
```

Which would return a collection containing the shape objects Rounded Rectangle 1, 2 & 3.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a shape Excel will automatically name it for you.  You can change this name by selecting the shape and changing it in the Name Box.

[image]

[image]

---

As @Rory pointed out, if your code is working then the shape is located on the MLS sheet.

Comment: Thank you, that is obviously right. It turns out that this portion of the code is unused and that the colors are set directly as background colors in the cells of the sheet. That is why I was confused.